# Change the menu colour in wordpress colibri theme

Tags: html, wordpress

I have tried everything, looked into the theme editor file but i couldn't find this code.
This is the code which is used there for the menu :-

```
#colibri .style-577 > div > .colibri-menu-container > ul.colibri-menu > li > a {
```

Where can I find this code?

Comment: _"where can i found this code?"_ - you likely won't find it anywhere in the server-side code exactly like that - because the `style-577` strongly suggests, that this gets generated dynamically. The rule for this is not contained in an external stylesheet - this has been written into a `style` element directly in the HTML source of the page.

Comment: But - this dynamic rule apparently containing a post ID or something like that, also strongly suggests that this will probably be _configurable_ somewhere in your theme's settings.

Comment: Where can I find the main index file so i can make the changes? please help me.

Comment: _"wordpress colibri theme change menu item color"_ typed into Google, first result: https://docs.colibriwp.com/knowledgebase/styling-menus/

Comment: Bro this is pro feature

Answer (score 1):

you can override theme css with it

```
.style-577 .colibri-menu-container ul#menu-colibri-menu li a {
    color: rgb(255 0 0) !important;
}
```

Comment: its not working!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to install a plugin that lets you edit the site's header and footer and embed JS to it. (Something like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-headers-and-footers/))

Try adding the following JS to the end of the body (because you want this to run after the code has executed and the style 577 is generated so that it can be overwritten):

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("style-577")[0];

element.classList.add("mystyle");

var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("mystyle")[0];

obj.style.setProperty("attribute", "value");

Comment: Do I have to apply the code in all of three section in the plugin with the script tag?

Comment: Just the end of body tag

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with a slightly different CSS:

```
.style-9 .colibri-menu-container ul.colibri-menu li a {
    color: red !important;
}

.style-9 .colibri-menu-container ul.colibri-menu li a:hover {
    color: green !important;
}
```

ofc you can also use hex values like #ffffff or rgb as color codes. You have to add it via menu customizer >>> general settings >>> additional css. maybe you also have to find out by examing the websites code wich .style-$NUMBER you have to chose.